# What is any ios device(arm64) in Xcode12?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, xcode12

I searched for this on the internet but I can't look the best definition and details about it. As far as I know, my ios head says that build the project first in "any ios device(arm64)" before sending a review to apple. And from my understanding, it tries to build in any ios device to ensures it can build to any of it.

Answer (score 0):

we always leave this option when we Archive the build and submit it to the App Store.

When you are developing an app, you must choose a specific device to run on. So that you cannot build with selected option "any ios device".